# Has Ubuntu been patched for KRACKs?

Tags: ubuntu, updates, krack

I updated my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

My `/var/log/apt/history.log` says that `linux-signed-image-3.13.0-134-generic:amd64` has been installed.

The [changelog page](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/main/proposed/linux-source-3.13.0) says

linux (3.13.0-134.183) trusty; urgency=low

> - linux: 3.13.0-134.183 -proposed tracker (LP: #1722335)
>
>   [ Thadeu Lima de Souza Cascardo ]    * CVE-2017-10661
>
>   - timerfd: Protect the might cancel mechanism proper
> - CVE-2017-10662
>
>   - f2fs: sanity check segment count
> - CVE-2017-10663
>
>   - f2fs: sanity check checkpoint segno and blkoff
> - CVE-2017-14340
>
>   - xfs: XFS_IS_REALTIME_INODE() should be false if no rt device present
> - CVE-2017-10911
>
>   - xen-blkback: don't leak stack data via response ring
> - CVE-2017-11176
>
>   - mqueue: fix a use-after-free in sys_mq_notify()
> - CVE-2016-8632
>
>   - tipc: check minimum bearer MTU
>
>   -- Juerg Haefliger  Tue, 10 Oct 2017 13:23:11
>     +0200

This does not look like patch for the [Key Reinstallation Attacks](https://www.krackattacks.com).

Should I assume that a patch has not been released yet? Was it released prior to the divulgation of the attacks? Do I wait?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Linux kernel itself is not affected. The part responsible for WPA is wpasupplicant. From [the Changelog](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/main/security/wpasupplicant):

> Version: 2.1-0ubuntu1.5   2017-10-16 17:06:43 UTC
>     wpa (2.1-0ubuntu1.5) trusty-security; urgency=medium
>
> - SECURITY UPDATE: Multiple issues in WPA protocol
>
>   - debian/patches/2017-1/*.patch: Add patches from Debian jessie
>   - CVE-2017-13077, CVE-2017-13078, CVE-2017-13079, CVE-2017-13080, 
>       CVE-2017-13081, CVE-2017-13082, CVE-2017-13086, CVE-2017-13087, 
>       CVE-2017-13088

Comment: For those not aware, the CVEs listed in this answer match the CVEs listed in the CERT database for the "Krack" vulnerability.